# Menu launcher under activities

Tags: launcher

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 a couple of days ago. Half way through the screen went black and the P.C. shut down. I was able to complete the upgrade after accessing help via my wife's P.C. and everything is there and up and running. BUT.. There is no sidebar menu launcher on desktop. Instead, there is ACTIVITIES at the top left hand corner. When I click this I see the applications and can create the launcher sidebar. BUT ONLY in the ACTIVITIES window. To do anything I have to click on what I want in the activities window then it goes to desktop. To switch to something else, I have to go to Activities window again. Can anybody please help?

Comment: Are you using gnome desktop ? Does it look like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c2/Shows_Overview_mode_(%22Activities%22)_in_GNOME_3.8.png/1024px-Shows_Overview_mode_(%22Activities%22)_in_GNOME_3.8.png) ? Because there's no "Activities" menu in default Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Hi Serg, Thanks for responding. To tell the truth I don't know what desktop I'm using or how to find out. Gwyn

Comment: Yes it does look like that How do I add photos here to show you ?

Comment: Just upload it to imgur and provide link in the comments.

Comment: Have you considered doing a fresh install which doesn't involve a sudden shutdown in the middle of the process?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Sorry to be a numpty. It was so simple in the end, I never thought of it. Thanks to Serg's comment, it got me thinking. Somehow the Desktop had been switched to Gnome during the upgrade. I simply switched back to Ubuntu on startup and it works fine. Thanks Serg.